# DataGridView not showing the information

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview

I´m trying to have my datagridviewDocumentos showing the SP information and its just posting blank in my windowsForm.
First there is my DataAccess Class.

```
    public DataTable Sp_Teste(int JobID, int BatchID)
    {

        try
        {
            ManageConnectionStateIbml1();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS", 
            connectionIBML1);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobID", JobID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchID", BatchID);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            ManageConnectionStateIbml1();
            connectionIBML1.Close();
           
        }
 
    }
```

Then there is my form.cs, please ignore the first two regions that are my other two datagrids

```
    public void Update(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        #region DatagridViewOCR
        dataGridViewOCR.ColumnCount = 4;
        DataGridViewColumn columnBatchID = dataGridViewOCR.Columns[0];
        columnBatchID.Width = 130;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDOCID = dataGridViewOCR.Columns[1];
        columnDOCID.Width = 130;
        DataGridViewColumn columnOCR_DATA = dataGridViewOCR.Columns[2];
        columnOCR_DATA.Width = 130;
        DataGridViewColumn columnFetch_Name = dataGridViewOCR.Columns[3];
        columnFetch_Name.Width = 130;
        dataGridViewOCR.Columns[0].Name = "BatchID";
        dataGridViewOCR.Columns[1].Name = "DOCID";
        dataGridViewOCR.Columns[2].Name = "OCR_DATA";
        dataGridViewOCR.Columns[3].Name = "Fetch_Name";
        #endregion

        #region DatagridViewDados
        dataGridViewDados.ColumnCount = 5;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDataDoc = dataGridViewDados.Columns[0];
        columnDataDoc.Width = 120;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDataCliente = dataGridViewDados.Columns[1];
        columnDataCliente.Width = 120;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDataData = dataGridViewDados.Columns[2];
        columnDataData.Width = 120;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDataTipoDoc = dataGridViewDados.Columns[3];
        columnDataTipoDoc.Width = 120;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDataOutros = dataGridViewDados.Columns[3];
        columnDataOutros.Width = 120;
        dataGridViewDados.Columns[0].Name = "DOC";
        dataGridViewDados.Columns[1].Name = "Cliente";
        dataGridViewDados.Columns[2].Name = "Data";
        dataGridViewDados.Columns[3].Name = "TipoDoc";
        dataGridViewDados.Columns[4].Name = "Outros";
        #endregion

        #region DatagridViewDocumentos
        int JobID = 
        Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewDocumentos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        int BatchID = 
        Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewDocumentos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource = null;
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Refresh();
       
       
       
        DataGridViewColumn columnCaixa = dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[0];
        columnCaixa.Width = 50;
        DataGridViewColumn columnDOC = dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[1];
        columnDOC.Width = 50;
        DataGridViewColumn columnID = dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[2];
        columnID.Width = 50;
        DataGridViewColumn columnPROC = dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[3];
        columnPROC.Width = 50;

        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Add(columnCaixa);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Add(columnDOC);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Add(columnID);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Add(columnPROC);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.ColumnCount = 4;

        
        DataTable dt = da.Sp_Teste(JobID, BatchID);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource = dt;
        #endregion


    }
}
```

This is my sp:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS
@JobID INT,
@BatchID INT
AS
BEGIN

SELECT top(10) i.*
from jobtable as j
  inner join batchtable as b
  on j.JobID = b.JobID
  inner join imgtable as i
  on i.BatchID = b.BatchID
END
GO
```

Hope you guys can help me out, right now im not having any errors show up.

Comment: Does the DataTable returned from Sp_Teste contain any data?

Comment: if you want i can post my sp too @Crowcoder

Comment: Still same question. Are you debugging it to see if it is bringing back any data?

Comment: @Crowcoder thats the thing im not able to debug, it goes straight into the app not letting me debug

Comment: Do you know how to use breakpoints and step through code?

Comment: I know how to use breakpoints but what do you mean by step trough code? @Crowcoder

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: that is what im trying to do, and like i said its not letting me since it goes straight to the windows form app

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "goes straight to the windows form app". I don't have your app, I can't try it myself. I don't have your database nor the parameter values you are using to see if it returns data. Most likely you are getting an error but you are swallowing it somewhere. You can break on all exceptions during debugging by checking the box in "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the Exception Settings window from the Debug menu > windows > Exception Settings.

Comment: can you point to me where i should do the break point then please cause everywhere i put on it doesen´t let me run trough code

Comment: Your problem might not be in the code you have shown. Enable break on all exceptions like I said and see where the program blows up.

Comment: ok i will try that @Crowcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove this line `dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Clear();` and check what happens

Do debug well,,,, Use key F10 for step debugging nd do check if Your sp returns any data.

Comment: hello brucode sorry for the delay i tried it out, the result is the same i tried debugging but like i said it doens´t let me it just goes into the app and doesn´t let me move from there with the debugging

Comment: can we see the code where you are calling this Update method.